# jQuery Date picker control with Update panel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have developed a Calendar User control with jQuery Date picker. Now my problem is when I am using this control in normal Web page all the required validations (like date cannot be greater that Current date etc) are firing perfectly, but when I am place this user control inside an Update panel after the partial page refresh all the jQuery validations stop firing. Any idea about this strange behavior?

Answer (score 2):

A partial refresh means that there are no longer events bound to the jQuery controls, because the controls have been rendered again, but the jQuery to bind to them has not.

You can fix this with live(), delegate(), or on() (depending on your version of jQuery) or you can register your scripts with the ScriptManager so that they run again after a partial reload.

More detail:

Use [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx) to register a script with the ScriptManager.  The script should run any time the UpdatePanel loads or reloads.  I haven't played with this in a long time, since I started using MVC, so I probably won't be much more help.

Comment: How to register scripts with the ScriptManager ? any live example would help me.